# Python 3.6.3, libtcod-cffi, pip: installation fails

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6

I'm trying to install libtcod-cffi on Ubuntu 17.10, Python 3.6.3.

First: I've installed via apt: gcc, libsdl2-dev, libffi-dev, libomp-dev, python3-dev, which is needed by libtcod-cffi.

Second: I'm trying to install `pip install libtcod-cffi` in virtualenv. Installation fails. You can see the insstallation output here: https://pastebin.com/EGhqaEL3

What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Apparently this problem exists when using Python 3.6. I've downgraded Python interpreter to 3.5 and everything works fine.